# Как добавить в SurfaceView layout.xml

Tags: android

Здравствуйте. Как я могу добавить к камере  layout.xml с элементами управления, кнопки и т.д.?  Вот у меня main_activity.

```
public class MainScreen extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(new CameraView(this));
    }
}
```

В него вкладывается вот эта камера:

```
public class CameraView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private Camera camera;

    public CameraView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        getHolder().addCallback(this);
        getHolder().setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        camera = Camera.open();
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        Camera.Parameters p = camera.getParameters();
        p.setPreviewSize(width, height);
        camera.setParameters(p);
        try {
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        camera.startPreview();
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        camera.stopPreview();
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
    }
}
```

А камере, мне нужно дать элементы управления

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вот в xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/activity_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context="com.example.ruslan.myapplication.MainScreen">

        <SurfaceView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/surfaceView" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
        <Button
                android:text="Button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" android:id="@+id/button"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Как мне сделать, чтобы эти кнопки показывались вместе с камерой?

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        View cameraView = factory.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
        setContentView(cameraView);
    }

}
```

камера

```
public class CameraView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private Camera camera;

    public CameraView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        getHolder().addCallback(this);
        getHolder().setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        camera = Camera.open();
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        Camera.Parameters p = camera.getParameters();
        p.setPreviewSize(width, height);
        camera.setParameters(p);
        try {
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        camera.startPreview();
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        camera.stopPreview();
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
    }
}
```

layout.xml.
Указываем пакет с камерой.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <com.myCompany.testtwolayers.CameraView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```